# VSCode PHP Xdebug not showing DateTime object content

Tags: php, datetime, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I updated Xdebug because I updated PHP and now the content of `DateTime` objects is no longer shown in the debugger. I know there once was a fix for this problem but although I searched the internet up and down I can't find it anymore.

I'm using Xdebug 2.8.1, VSCode Xdebug extension v1.27.0 and PHP Intelephense v1.8.2

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, the problem could be reproduced by the developers of Xdebug on GitHub for this particular version installed (Xdebug 2.8.1). The problem can be solved bei either updating to the latest 2.x version of Xdebug or even better to version 3.
See resolved issue on GitHub here:
https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/820